# how to refresh two After Insert process

Tags: php

After insert successfully i want to refresh the two page which i opened ,

Example :

i have Order view display ,

in this am displaying the order added items ,

And another is the pop up window , i want to refresh this window ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some javascript in your popup to refresh the opener window. This requires the popup to be in the same domain as the opening page.

If you're using jQuery just add

```
$(function(){
   window.opener.location.reload()
});
```

Or you can add it to onload

```
<body onload="window.opener.location.reload()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple html in your head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=thankyou.htm">
```

Where content = seconds to refresh
and URL  = page to go to.

If you want to use php:

```
<?php
header("refresh: 5; thankyou.htm";
?>
```

headers can only be sent if there was no previous output or when you use output control functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php